# setState conflicts with getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export interface MyComponentProps {
  show: boolean;
}
export interface MyComponentState {
  show: boolean;
}

export default class App extends Component<MyComponentProps, MyComponentState> {
  static defaultProps = {
    show: true
  };
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props: MyComponentProps) {
    console.log("getDerivedStateFromProps: ", props);
    if ("show" in props) {
      return { show: props.show };
    }
    return null;
  }
  constructor(props: MyComponentProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: props.show
    };
  }
  onClick() {
    this.setState({ show: false });
  }
  render() {
    const { show } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {show ? "teresa teng" : ""}
        <button type="button" onClick={() => this.onClick()}>
          toggle
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`getDerivedStateFromProps()` static method will be executed after `setState()`. So I click the button to try to change the value of `state.show` to `false`, but the `getDerivedStateFromProps()` method will change `state.show` to `true`. So the text will always be visible.

`getDerivedStateFromProps` intends to use the props passed in by the parent component to update the state.

How can I solve this? Playground [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/setstate-conflicts-with-getderivedstatefromprops-lvmn2?file=/src/App.tsx).

Comment: What if you rename one of them?

Comment: Why is `show` both from the props *and* updated locally? If the value from the parent should be used, you could also pass a callback to update it, so using `props.onClick` when the button is clicked and not holding that state locally. [*"`getDerivedStateFromProps` is invoked right before calling the render method"*](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops), so will be called when the local state updates too.

Answer (score 1):

`getDerviedStateFromProps` is bound to run after every prop and state change. This was not an actual design but this change in functionality was introduced in React version 16.4 (if I remember correctly).

Now, if you want to update the local show i.e. your state on the basis of your props, you can:

1. Pass a callback which updates `show` for you in the parent component and then use the new prop value.(As mentioned by @jonrsharpe in the comments).
2. You can also make use of a `key` prop which tells your component to completely unmount and mount itself in case of a key change. This will lead to the state getting reset based on the value of the props.

For ex,

```
<App show={this.state.show} 
key={this.state.show}/>
```

Example [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-shockley-7t3yw)